# Minecraft server ping-status by powershell

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm making a simple mojang-api-based on powershell and I'm trying to know if there is any native way to ping/get status of aminecraft minecraft server. Until now I found that: `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("mc.hypixel.net")[0].IPAddressToString` can resolve an adress to `209.222.115.37`, When I try to ping it with a simple `ping 209.222.115.37` or `ping mc.hypixel.net` cannot connect to the server. So I tried with `telnet 209.222.115.37 25565` or `telnet mc.hypixel.net 25565` than It waits a little bit and than losts connection. I'm thinking if It's just some minecraft server(but I don't think so, because when I do it on my own server with localhost, same error with telnet, but works with ping)... Can someone tell me if there is any other way to do it by ping it(maybe sending special packets to make the server responde?)

PS: I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/admincraft/comments/2ajrm2/how_joining_a_server_works/) reddit that explains very good how does connection to a minecraft server work.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to write some PowerShell script for personal use? Or an actual API, that might be useful to other as well? Because I don't think you would want to write an API in PowerShell.

Comment: Just personal use.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround at the moment by using this googling: https://api.mcsrvstat.us/1/mc.hypixel.net and then `ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject ($(Invoke-webrequest -URI "https://api.mcsrvstat.us/1/mc.hypixel.net").Content)`, but I would like still to use something more easy.

Comment: This relies on a third party though